# Create plpgsql function from libpqxx

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, libpqxx

I haven't had much luck trying to create a function from within libpqxx.  I try calling exec with a string that contains the CREATE OR REPLACE function ... but I have never been able to get the syntax correct.  Any tips or links? Thanks!

Comment: Have you got your function working from `psql`? What symptoms are you seeing? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: First get it right in a tool like pgAdmin then build it into your code. Then when it still doesn't work post your code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to do it just passing the string "CREATE or REPLACE FUNCTION ..." via a pqxx::work.exec() call.  I must have had bad syntax before.  Thanks.